# Find the limit of exponent/factorial sequence

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial, exponential-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 0$, $x \in \Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r)
>   [Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215770/finding-lim-n-to-infty-frac-sqrtn2n)

I don't know how to even stoke it...

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty }  \frac{2^n}{n!} = $$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211502/prove-that-frac2nn-converges-0 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77550/prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracxnn-0-x-in-bbb-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

Prove that $$0 < \dfrac{2^n}{n!} \leq \dfrac4n$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ using induction and then use squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdots\cdots2}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdots\cdots n}
$$
In the next step after the one above, a lone "$2$" is added on top and $n+1$ on the bottom.  The number $2/(n+1)$ is small.  At each step you multiply by a small number.  (And they keep getting even smaller, although that is not essential to the problem.

That should tell you what limit they will approach.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked and answered recently.

To answer it yourself, look at the last $n/2$ terms of $n!$.
They are each at least $n/2$.
Compare the product of these with $2^n$ to show that
the ratio $2^n/n!$ goes to zero.